# How to pass data from a class and used in another class for calculation

Tags: java

i'm trying to do this feature where i calculate the calories needed in BMIcalculation class, then i created another class called CalorieIntake where in here i'll calculate the total calorie intake. (i do this by extends the BMIcalculation class.)

Then when i click on the 'Check' button, it should compare between this two value and show the interpretation. However i keep getting error at the 'interpretDiff(float diffValue)' part it mentioned it must return with a String value.

Here are my codes..pls help me to check where to problem is. Or is there a better way to do so? pls advice me. Thanks a lot..

```
public class CalorieIntake extends BMIcalculation {
    TextView counter1;
    Button compare;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.setContentView(R.layout.form_calorieintake2);

    Button btn_calcIntake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calcIntake);
    btn_calcIntake.setOnClickListener(btnListener_calcIntake);
    counter1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_totalCalorieIntake);

    Button compare = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.checkIntake); 
    compare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
try {           
        if ((!counter1.equals("")) && (!caloriesresult.equals(""))) 
            {                   
            TextView compareText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.compareLabel);   
            EditText counter1E = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView_totalCalorieIntake);   
            EditText caloriesresultE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.caloriesText);

            float calorieIntake = Float.parseFloat(counter1E.getText().toString().trim());
            float calorieNeed = Float.parseFloat(caloriesresultE.getText().toString().trim());                      

            float diffValue = calDiff(calorieIntake, calorieNeed);      

            String calInterpretation = interpretDiff(diffValue);

            compareText.setText("Difference of" + diffValue + " : " + calInterpretation);
            }
   }catch (Exception k)
            { System.out.println(k);
              Toast.makeText(CalorieIntake.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }   
    }
    private String interpretDiff(float diffValue) 
    {
        if (diffValue < 100)
        {
        return "Eat more";
        }
    }

    private float calDiff(float calorieIntake, float calorieNeed) {         
        return (float) (calorieIntake - calorieNeed);
    }    
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In interpretDiff, what happens if diffValue is not less than 100?  You return nothing. However, java requires that you return something, as that is what the declaration of the method implies.

A solution would be:

```
private String interpretDiff(float diffValue) 
{
    if (diffValue < 100) 
        return "Eat more";
    return "Eat less";
}
```

The else statement for if diffValue is not less than 100 is not necessary here because the second return statement is only called if diffValue >= 100 (since hitting a return statement exits out of the method).

With regards to the issue of the exception being thrown, and the Toast error being called, that can only happen as a result of the following code:

```
        TextView compareText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.compareLabel);   
        EditText counter1E = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView_totalCalorieIntake);   
        EditText caloriesresultE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.caloriesText);

        float calorieIntake = Float.parseFloat(counter1E.getText().toString().trim());
        float calorieNeed = Float.parseFloat(caloriesresultE.getText().toString().trim());                      

        float diffValue = calDiff(calorieIntake, calorieNeed);      

        String calInterpretation = interpretDiff(diffValue);

        compareText.setText("Difference of" + diffValue + " : " + calInterpretation);
```

Assuming findViewById doesn't have an issue in it, the error is probably coming from getting the text of counter1E, caloriesresultE (if they are null). If neither of those are null, then check to make sure callDiff and interpretDiff don't have bugs in them. Finally, make sure compareText is not null.

Comment: Thanks a lot ~..this solves the error. However it still goes to the exception loop, and returning the Error toast when i click on the button.. do u know what i'm missing here?

Comment: @Onered I've updated my post with some reasons why an error can be caused. Can you tell me the exact data that you get from the exception that is printed out (which line, what kind of exception, etc.)

Comment: Thanks..i was trying to check where the problem comes from too, but i cant see anything in LogCat, it's blank and i dunno why it captures nothing there..

Comment: Ah I see, instead of System.out.println(k); in the exception try replacing it with k.printStackTrace(); and see if there is anything in the error logs? (I'm not sure how to check errors in Android, sorry)

Comment: actually what i was trying to do is: get the calculated calorie intake data from 'textView_totalCalorieIntake' (and put it into counter1E); get the calculated calorie needed from 'caloriesText' (and put it into caloriesresultE); compareText is a place i prepare for it to show the setText("Difference of" + ......). I think it is not allow to do so, but how should i modify that?

Comment: Oh i've just tried replacing that with k.printStackTrace();  but still no error captured..

Comment: Hmm thats interesting. Try printing out if compareText, counter1E, and caloriesresultE are null? If the log still remains empty then I'm not sure what to do (I don't know why the log isn't working). Its a little hard to debug when the logging isn't working :(

Comment: Thanks..i just restarted my Eclipse and rerun, and now the LogCat able to show the errors..which one should i check ya?

Comment: You can either paste it here or go to http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/Debugging?password= so we can chat and I can try to help you debug (so we don't flood this thread)